# getXmlEncoding() is giving the wrong output

Tags: java, xml, dom, encoding

I want to use Java to get the encoding style of a XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<company>
 <staff>
  <firstname>yong</firstname>
  <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
  <nickname>ä</nickname>
  <salary>100000</salary>
 </staff>
</company>
```

with the following java code:

```
public class SimpleXml 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File(PathInfo.getTestXmlFile());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("XmlEncoding: " + doc.getXmlEncoding());
            System.out.println("InputEncoding: " + doc.getInputEncoding());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the output that i am getting are:
XmlEncoding: ISO-8859-1
InputEncoding: UTF-8
And I really cannot figure out why do I get ISO-8859-1 while there is an UTF-8 in the XML header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine.

Xml File : `new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>ä</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

This is the code :

```
 public class XmlToJava {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\new.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("XmlEncoding: " + doc.getXmlEncoding());
            System.out.println("InputEncoding: " + doc.getInputEncoding());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output (Eclipse IDE) :

```
XmlEncoding: UTF-8
InputEncoding: UTF-8
```

But I'm guessing that some different encoding standard that your IDE may follow. Check for that.

Comment: is the exception occurs because the system cannot find the XML file? Or what exactly happens here?
I see that you are forcing the input source to be UTF-8? however, I want to read the Information from the XML header which Encoding style should be use to parse that XML file

Comment: I have updated my answer. It's showing the output : UTF-8 for both